# Add-on to view javascript-generated source code?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, view-source

I know it's possible to save as... and look at the html file and see all the classes generated by javascript, but I would love to know if there's a firefox (or other browser) add-on which will show me page source with the javascript generated classes.

Working with jQuery mobile and trying to carefully modify all the CSS it generates is tough without it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Firebug.  It's a line-level javascript debugger for firefox.  It will show you all of your script code and even let you step debug it.

To view generated mark-up, use the element inspector (the blue "box & arrow" icon in the top left of the firebug toolbar).  The element inspector allows you to hover over elements on your page and view its markup.

Comment: I have firebug- great tool. However I'm talking about seeing the markup it generates- so not the script- the live markup.

Comment: Using the element inspector in firebug lets you see the generated markup.  It's the little blue box and arrow icon in the top left of the firebug toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try "View Source Selection".

Right click page and `Select All` and right click again to `View Selection Source` to view the source that a script generated,  in FF. (at least in v.3.?)